# Is it possible increment sequence based on table id using batchupdate in java?

Tags: java, jdbctemplate

I am using `batchUpdate` with jdbc template.In that I want to increment a table column based on table id.I am using below code but getting exception.

```
 String sql = "INSERT INTO TEMP (Table_Id, STATUS, VERSION,Name) " +
                    "VALUES (?, ?, SELECT (VERSION+1) FROM (SELECT VERSION, Table_Id, MAX(VERSION) OVER(PARTITION BY Table_Id) MAX_V FROM TEMP ) WHERE Table_Id = ? AND VERSION = MAX_V, ?)";

    getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
      @Override
      public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i){
      try {
         TDetails customer = chngCustStus.get(i);
         ps.setInt(1, customer.getTableId());
         ps.setInt(1, customer.getStatus());
         ps.setInt(1, customer.getTableId());
         ps.setInt(1, customer.getName());
      } catch (SQLException e) {
         //TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    @Override
    public int getBatchSize() {
      return chngCustStus.size();
    }
```

Comment: If you get an exception, Add the stacktrace.

Comment: Yes,I am getting exception.In this way is there any solution is there..?

Comment: Why you do not Add the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

I think getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate is not possible to increment sequence generation because Once total insert list prepared as batch file then after connect to data base,So before connection not possible to sequence increment.